# What is Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.dll and Purpose?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, dacpac

What is Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.dll?

I am trying to see what it does in Microsoft Msdn technical documentation. Don't think Microsoft has  page for this. Just curious what this is used for? Is it only applied to deploy sql databases dacpac through Powershell?

I am researching for the actual SQL Server installation artifacts, not .Net namespace in comments.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DAC\bin

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.dac?view=sql-dacfx-140.3881.1?

Comment: @GSerg I am researching for the actual SQL Server installation artifacts, not .Net namespace

Comment: That dll contains this namespace and nothing else. Is that not what you are asking about?